# Thinking vs Talking in mind

Tags: reference-request, daily-life, samadhi, guidance, sati

Sometimes, I caught me on talking in mind. Sometimes my tongue moves according to it. Sometimes I talk to myself. This feels very fast and hard to control.

There also intuition like thinking. For a example, to move a hand we don't have to say to move. Also I can read a book without moving the tongue. (mind talking) This feels very calm. I like to be in this state. When I want start a work, I need to make my mind silent.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Talking mind is from accumulation of *emotion-creating* past actions & tendencies.

Silent intuitive mind is a right concentration when performing what is necessary to perform.

Possibly [MN 19](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ati/tipitaka/mn/mn.019.than.html) can help in understanding the different layers of the mind.

As [MN 117](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ati/tipitaka/mn/mn.117.than.html) refers to wrong thought (resolve) vs right thought (resolve).

Every human life is born with unwholesome and wholesome tendencies. This is what is going on here. Thus the Buddha distinguished mental phenomena (dhammas) as wholesome and unwholesome. Refer to [MN 9](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.009.ntbb.html) and "the elements" in [MN 115](https://suttacentral.net/mn115/en/sujato).